# How can I perform multiple random.choices tests

Tags: python, loops, random

I have a list called marbles. marbels = 10.000 items (5000 blue and 5000 red)

I want to perform a test where "def A1.primo():" will calculate and return measured random events more repeated in smaller samples than larger ones. Use (k=4, k=7)

```py
import random

marbles = ["RED" for _ in range(5000)] + ["BLUE" for _ in range(5000)]
A = random.choices(marbles, k=4) 
print(A) # this will print a list of 4 random Items from the list
```

How could I optimize code to then save returned numbers from A1.primo into a csv.file

Comment: Yes, for loops.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

```
for x in range(4):
    print(random.choice(marbles))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sampling with and without replacement

It's important to understand the difference between sampling with replacement and without replacement. Say we have a bag of 1 blue and 2 red marbles, and you select 2 marbles. If you put the marble back after pulling the first marble, it's possible to endup with 2 blue marbles. This is called sampling *with* replacement. Using `random.choice` is sampling *with* replacement.

### random.choices() and random.sample()

You can pull more than one element using the `choices()` function from the `random` module. For example sampling 4 marbles from a bag of 1 red and 2 blue marbles *with* replacement:

```
>>> import random
>>> marbles = ['red'] * 1 + ['blue'] * 2
>>> random.choices(marbles, k=4)
['red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
```

You can use sampling *without* replacement using the `random` module using the `sample` function:

```
>>> random.sample(marbles, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 482, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

As expected, this gives an error. You can't draw 4 marbles from a bag of 3. Now if we put 1000 red marbles and 2000 blue marbles in the bag, we get:

```
>>> marbles = ['red'] * 1000 + ['blue'] * 2000
>>> random.sample(marbles, 4)
['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red']
```

### Memory usage and weights

A possible problem with the examples above is that, if you have more marbles, you need a lot of memory. Therefore, the `choice()` function has a `weights` parameter. You can use it like this:

```
>>> marbles = ['red', 'blue']
>>> weights = [1000, 2000]
>>> random.choices(marbles, weights=weights, k=4)
['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red']
```

Sadly, the `random` module doesn't have a function for sampling without replacement using weights.

### Repeated sampling using for loop

Finally, we need to count the outcomes. A more advanced way to do this is using dictionaries and `defaultdict` from the `collections` module. As an alternative, we will create a list of outcomes, and loop through the different outcomes using a set of that list.

import random

SAMPLE_SIZE = 4
REPEAT_SAMPLING = 100

```
outcomes = []
marbles = ['red'] * 5000 + ['blue'] * 5000

for i in range(REPEAT_SAMPLING):
    outcome = ', '.join(random.sample(marbles, SAMPLE_SIZE))
    outcomes.append(outcome)

for outcome in set(outcomes):
    print(f'{outcome} appeared {outcomes.count(outcome)} times out of {REPEAT_SAMPLING}')
```